# iPhone text messages are delivered to my work iPad!

Tags: iphone, ipad, sms

My iPhone text messages are delivered to my work iPad, what is happening and how can I put it right?

Comment: Are you speaking about emails or messages? If messages then why would you use mail tag?

Comment: "Put it right?" It doing what it's designed to do!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the iMessage setting on your iPad. Follow these steps:

- Go to Settings > Messages
- Tap on the Send & Receive
- The next window will list all the accounts and/or numbers you can be reached on with the iPad
- Uncheck the iPhone mobile phone number listed
- Make any other necessary changes
- Exit your settings

Hope this helps!